# Git - alias with log pretty

Tags: git

I'm using this to create a log on online with hash name and date

`git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"`

I'd like put this into an alias, so I did

`git config --global alias.lp log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"`

but this appears in the config as

`lp = log`

Is it possible to use this in an alias

Comment: You're missing quotes, try `git config --global alias.lp 'log --pretty-format="..."'`

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, it worked thanks